# Invalid use of incomplete type (class method specialization)

Tags: c++, templates, c++11, compiler-errors, template-specialization

First, I've read over many other questions and couldn't find the solution.  So before marking it a duplicate, please make sure duplicate answers the question.

I'm trying to specialize `F::operator()` for a class `C2`; however, `C2` has a template parameter and I want `F::operator()` to behave the same for all `C2`'s.

Compiler error:

`error: invalid use of incomplete type ‘struct F<C2<T> >’
 void F<C2<T>>::operator()()`

Also, instead of `Handle& h`, I tried `Handle* h` and received the same error.

```
#include<iostream>

struct C1
{
        void foo()
        {
                std::cout << "C1 called" << std::endl;
        }
};

template<typename T>
struct C2
{
        void bar();
};

template<>
void C2<int>::bar()
{
        std::cout << "C2<int> called" << std::endl;
}

template<typename Handle>
struct F
{
        F(Handle& h_) : h(h_) {}

        void operator()();

        Handle& h;
};

template<>
void F<C1>::operator()()
{
        h.foo();
}

template<typename T>
void F<C2<T>>::operator()()
{
        h.bar();
}

int main()
{
        C1 c1; 
        F<C1> f_c1 (c1);
        f_c1();

        C2<int> c2; 
        F<C2<int>> f_c2 (c2);
        f_c2();
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's no such thing like a partial specialization of a member function. You'd need to first partial-specialize the entire class:

```
template <typename T>
struct F<C2<T>>
{
    void operator()();
};

template <typename T>
void F<C2<T>>::operator()() {}
```

Since this is a heavy-weight solution, alternatively, you can exploit tag-dispatching:

```
template <typename T> struct tag {};

template <typename Handle>
struct F
{
    F(Handle& h_) : h(h_) {}

    void operator()()
    {
        call(tag<Handle>{});
    }

private:    
    void call(tag<C1>)
    {
        h.foo();
    }

    template <typename T>
    void call(tag<C2<T>>)
    {
        h.bar();
    }

    Handle& h;
};
```

[**DEMO**](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bb56f4e55acb84f0)